# How to create API in laravel for android?

Tags: android, laravel, api, laravel-5.4

I need to create an API in the Laravel for android. I have no idea from where to start. It has been only two weeks I have started learning android development. Please guide me!

Comment: Google it..you will find many links..Here no one is going to code anything for you

Comment: @Xantosh Lamsal Start looking Lumen , it's laravel micro-framework. generally used for API's in laravel. you can also work on API with Laravel framework also.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you. It is not any magic formula for that, you just need to read laravel docs.
https://laravel.com/api/5.4/index.html

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you are in a hurry, maybe you should check [Android Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) to build a simple API.

But, with laravel the the basic steps are:

1. Create a database structure
2. On installed laravel, created Model classes to access the created tables
3. Create Routes and Controllers to access the models.

You can use

> Route::resource()

to easily access controllers with basic CRUD methods to your api (index, create, store, show etc)
or use

> Route::controller()

to customize your methods, including the type of HTTP method to access (putName(), getName(), postName())

Each controller should return a response in Json format, to be accessed by your Android Client

> return response()->json($records, 200);

With these basic steps, you can start an MVP.

But there are things you should search to improve the api:

1. API security,
2. Restful Apis

Comment: You can actually just return $records. When you return a model or a collection of models, Laravel will automatically serialize into a json response.